# commandlink in JSF not generating the intended HTML tag

Tags: jsf, href, commandlink

I'm trying to call a managed bean from `h:commandLink` in JSF. But I don't see `href` attribute in the rendered HTML `a` tag.

Am I missing something?

There is a ManagedBean called `AccountSetupController` with  a `signUp` method in it.

**This is the tag I used in JSF:**

```
  <h:form prependId="false">
    <h:commandLink  action="#{accountSetupController.signUp()}" 
         value="#{msg['homepage.createaccount']}" styleClass="button large">
    </h:commandLink>
  </h:form>
```

**This is the rendered tag. See there is nothing in href attribute.**

```
 <a href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('j_idt15'),
  {'j_idt33':'j_idt33'},'');return false" 
  class="button large">CREATE MY ACCOUNT</a>
```

**This is the form tag that is generated**

```
    <form id="j_idt15" name="j_idt15" 
    method="post" action="/myproject/faces/homepage/homepage.xhtml" 
    enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">       .... </form>
```

As you can see, the form action is pointing to some place I don't need.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Related: [h:outputLink vs h:commandLink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink/)

Answer (score 3):

Command links in JSF are rendered that way. The form will be submitted by JSF via JavaScript's `onclick` method using JSF JS library, while the `href` will always stay `#`.

Moreover, you won't find the bound action / action listener method names in browser tools due to understandable reasons. Rather, JSF will find the id of a clicked link on the server and will trigger all of the component's action(listeners).

All in all, reading [`<h:commandLink>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/commandLink.html) documentation unsurprisingly helps a lot (all emphasis mine):

> General behavior: Both the encode and decode behavior require the ability to get the **id/name for a hidden field, which may be rendered in markup or which may be programmatically added via client DOM manipulation, whose value is set by the JavaScript form submit** (further referred to as hiddenFieldName.
>
> Decode behavior: Obtain the "clientId" property of the component. **Obtain the Map from the "requestParameterMap" property of the ExternalContext. Derive hiddenFieldName as above. Get the entry in the Map under the key that is the hiddenFieldName.** If the there is no entry, or the entry is the empty String, or the entry is not equal to the value of the "clientId" property, return immediately. **If there is an entry, and its value is equal to the value of the "clientId" property, create a new javax.faces.event.ActionEvent instance around the component and call queueActionEvent() on the component**, passing the event.
>
> Encode behavior: **Render "#" as the value of the "href" attribute**. Render the current value of the component as the link text if it is specified. **Render JavaScript that is functionally equivalent to the following as the value of the "onclick" attribute: document.forms['CLIENT_ID']['hiddenFieldName'].value='CLIENT_ID'; ocument.forms['CLIENT_ID']['PARAM1_NAME'].value='PARAM1_VALUE'; document.forms['CLIENT_ID']['PARAM2_NAME'].value='PARAM2_VALUE'; return false; document.forms['CLIENT_ID'].submit()"** where hiddenFieldName is as described above, CLIENT_ID is the clientId of the UICommand component, PARAM*_NAME and PARAM*_VALUE are the names and values, respectively, of any nested UIParameter children.